# SASS/SCSS's @if for choosing the type of image to use?

Tags: css, image, if-statement, sass

It's my first try using the `@if` control directive from [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#id10).

I have a list of optimized images in a folder.  Some of them are smaller as JPGs and others are smaller as PNGs.

With the `@if` rule I'm trying to say **"if a JPG of that file exists use this @include, else use the other one."**

*(The gif's in the example are there to clarify whether the "else if" part is right.)*

#### My Example:

```
$list: A, B, C;

$type: jpg;

@mixin portfolio-images {
    @each $item in $list {
        a[href*="#{$item}"] span {

            /* @if starts */   

            @if $type == jpg {@include background-image-retina("#{$item}.jpg");}
            @else if $type == png {@include background-image-retina("#{$item}.png");}
            @else {@include background-image-retina("#{$item}.gif");}

            /* @if ends */   


            @include hide-text;
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
        }
    }
}
```

The JPGs display fine, but the PNGs don't display at all - no output is compiled in the CSS file.

I use the [@include background-image-retina](http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2012/03/09/compass-sass-mixins-for-simple-retina-images-on-websites/) and can't define a custom variable for image type like in [this](https://gist.github.com/1210421) fabulous mixin. So I'm not sure how to approach this.

---

**Update:** Like @lnrbob pointed out - it is not possible to check for existence of files with SASS. I marked his answer as correct since he provided an excellent @if example and in the long run helped me with this in understanding this SASS feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused what you are doing here. SASS won't check your file system to see if `A.jpg` or 'A.png` exists. You need to update the variable. So in your example (I think) it should look like this:

```
$list: A, B, C;

@mixin portfolio-images($type: 'jpg') {
    @each $item in $list {
        a[href*="#{$item}"] span {

            /* @if starts */   

            @if $type == jpg {@include background-image-retina("#{$item}.jpg");}
            @else if $type == png {@include background-image-retina("#{$item}.png");}
            @else {@include background-image-retina("#{$item}.gif");}

            /* @if ends */   


            @include hide-text;
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd use it like:

```
@include portfolio-images('png');
```

---

I don't think this is what you are wanting to achieve though is it? If you are wanting to replicate the functionality of the retina-compass helper (which you've linked to as [@include background-image-retina](http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2012/03/09/compass-sass-mixins-for-simple-retina-images-on-websites/)) you need to do this as some ruby script to feed into the compiling process that SASS uses (in this example the helper uses [Compass](http://compass-style.org/)).

I hope this is, at least, mildly helpful. Please let me know if I've completely misunderstood and I'll review :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that SASS won't check my file system - I have for example: a.jpg and b.png. My aim was just to have one include, that's basically what I hoped to achieve. /// My assumption was if others could check via **@ if** if a certain color value exist that I could check for a type-condition too. I know see it's not possible because the output of the "@each" list isn't yet compiled. /// I guess I'll keep the my old version without the @if and simply build two lists (one for the jpg's, the other for png's).

Comment: no worries. Just remember the `@mixin` evaluates the parameters you send it. So in that colour example you linked to the SASS editor will specify the color in each case (unless they have set a default elsewhere, in which case they will be able to override the default in specific circumstances).